# Array of typed objects not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: typescript

I want to define an object according to type. Within that object is an array consisting of elements that also correspond to a given type. However, I want to only push elements to this array later and initialize it empty for now. But it gives me an error and I can't figure this out. I have the following lines in my **app.ts**:

```
const publishObject: MqttPublishObject = {
                        IsTurnedOff: detail.isTurnedOff,
                        processType: detail.processType.name === "linear" ? 0 : 1,
                        anchorPoints: <MqttPublishAnchorPoint>[]
                      };
```

For which I get this errors:

```
src/app/app.ts(51,25): error TS2322: Type 'MqttPublishAnchorPoint' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
src/app/app.ts(51,39): error TS2352: Conversion of type 'undefined[]' to type 'MqttPublishAnchorPoint' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
```

The typedefs are in the following files:

**mqttPublishObject.ts**:

```
export interface MqttPublishObject {
   IsTurnedOff : boolean;
   processType : number;
   anchorPoints : MqttPublishAnchorPoint[];
}
```

**mqttPublishAnchorPoint.ts**

```
export interface MqttPublishAnchorPoint {
    hour: number;
    minute: number;
    second: number;
    intensity: number;
}
```

I feel I'm going about it the wrong way, but I don't see how. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `<MqttPublishAnchorPoint>[]` means `[] as MqttPublishAnchorPoint`, not `[] as MqttPublishAnchorPoint[]`. This is probably the reason for error.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I solved it like this: <MqttPublishAnchorPoint[]>[]. If you care to answer the question I can make you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are essentially telling you two things:

- First error means that you're trying to assign value of type `MqttPublishAnchorPoint` to the field of type `MqttPublishAnchorPoint[]`. It means that TypeScript somehow is treating your array not as an array, but as a `MqttPublishAnchorPoint`.
- The reason for this is given by the second error: you're trying to cast some value of array type (`undefined[]`) to `MqttPublishAnchorPoint`, and TypeScript can't make any sense of this assertion, since types are non-overlapping.

The core reason for both these errors is the cast: `<T>[]` means `[] as T`, not `[] as T[]`, i.e. the cast is applied to array, not to its inner type. The fix is simple:

```
const publishObject: MqttPublishObject = {
  IsTurnedOff: detail.isTurnedOff,
  processType: detail.processType.name === "linear" ? 0 : 1,
  anchorPoints: <MqttPublishAnchorPoint[]>[],
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIEcxgAoFcBGANsAM4AWA8vgFYQJjIDeAUMsnCAmQPZTbegwJZAC40mHAWLkAgpx58B4ANoBdANzMAvs2aDo8JOKx4ipMnK69%20gpq2T6QJYGACeYkLgC2%20aJp3MCNxODAAOUuZUtPRiGCYR5FF0DAC8dmwcVoqCJGIAPHGSZrLy1kpgagB8agA02upAA) (simplified by removing everything that doesn't matter for reproducing error).

---

However, in this case you don't ever need the cast. Since the variable is strongly typed, TypeScript is able to infer the array type without specifying it explicitly near the value:

```
const publishObject: MqttPublishObject = {
  IsTurnedOff: detail.isTurnedOff,
  processType: detail.processType.name === "linear" ? 0 : 1,
  anchorPoints: [], // inferred as MqttPublishAnchorPoint[]
};
```